# Highlight linux shell commands

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting

I have a log of new commands I use and my own tips/descriptions with them inside a text file.

I noticed there is DOS Batch code highlighting which highlights DOS commands.  Is there one for Linux shell commands?  I have the latest gedit-plugins(gedit-plugins (3.10.1-1ubuntu2) installed.

**Edit:** (log file snippet)

Linux.txt

```
7/10/2014
=========
netstat -an | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN' (get a list of listening ports)
find / -name "jenkins*"  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied" 
  (get list of files that are not Permission denied)

7/14/2014
=========
setterm -blank (disables screen timeout)
vmware settings > options, /mnt/hgfs/ (Set up VMware host shared folder)
sudo cp -avr /mnt/hgfs/C/Perl64/cpan/sources/modules /etc/perl/CPAN
   (copied folder from shared windows folder to ubuntu, for perl modules)
ctrl+flag(windows key)+arrow (same as windows key+arrow to position window)
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal (install nautilus)
nautilus -q (reset nautilus)
   (now you can open terminal from current folder in file browse)
```

I tried the *sh* syntax highlighting, but it doesn't highlight netstat or the second sudo command for some reason.

Also, on second thought, I'm thinking I might as well keep this as simple text file and use 'Changelog' maybe to highlight the === underlining I have, because this is a mix of shell commands plus Linux shortcut keys, and I have the description in () brackets, so it may not work out anyway.  Not sure why I want to keep track of dates, I know there's good references online anyways, so it's just for me to keep track of commands/use as a reference.

Should I close/delete this question, or does anyone think this is at all useful, or have any good suggestions to keep track of useful commands?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us an example of your file. What kind of commands would these be?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to "sh" for the syntax?

Comment: @BriGuy Thanks for the tip.  I tried it and updated the question with that test